# Julia: how to select all columns from a DataFrame satisfying a certain condition?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Say I want to select all float columns in the dataset. Is there a more convenient syntax than

```
cols = [eltype(col) <: Float64 for col in eachcol(df)]

select(df, cols)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aternatively you can write:

```
select(df, names(df, Float64))
```

or

```
df[:, names(df, Float64)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorize the list comprehension:

```
select(df, eltype.(eachcol(df)) .<: Float64)
```

---

Example of using vectorization:

```
julia> df = [[1,2,3], ['f', 'j'], [1.2, 2.3]]
3-element Vector{Vector{T} where T}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 ['f', 'j']
 [1.2, 2.3]

julia> eltype.(df)
3-element Vector{DataType}:
 Int64
 Char
 Float64

julia> eltype.(df) .<: Float64
3-element BitVector:
 0
 0
 1
```